# Как передать данные объекта между событиями ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть событие

```
 el.addEventListener(
      'dragstart',
      function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('id', this.getAttribute("data-id"));
  })
```

Тут я без проблем могу использовать dataTransfer и в другом событии могу прочитать.

А как это сделать для tablet событий т.е.

```
 el.addEventListener(
      'touchstart',
      function(e) {
  //....
  })
```

тут же dataTransfer никакой не передается.

Как мне передать какой то параметр в след событие например "touchend" ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте переменную:

```
var data; 

 el.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
     data = {time:Date.now()};
 })

 el.addEventListener('touchend',function(e) {
     console.log('touhstart time',data.time);
 })
```